Freezing NFS-based video playback
I have a NFS server (Intel J4125 CPU @ 2.00GHz (4C/4T), 8GB of RAM), hosting a NFS server configured as:
# /etc/nfs.conf                                             
[nfsd]
threads=16
vers3=false
vers4=true
vers4.0=false
vers4.1=false
vers4.2=true

And a client configured as:
# /etc/fstab
# This is a generated file.  Do not edit!
#
# To make changes, edit the fileSystems and swapDevices NixOS options
# in your /etc/nixos/configuration.nix file.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# Filesystems.
# ....
192.168.0.42:/crucial /home/black/barracuda nfs x-systemd.automount,noauto 0 0

$ nfsstat -m

/home/black/barracuda from 192.168.0.42:/crucial
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.0.10,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.0.42

My server hosts video files and from time to time, the playback stops for several, as if vlc was loading the file (I have less than 100 KB/s inbound on my client).
Despite:

My client is not busy (<10% CPU, <10% RAM, <20 KB/s outbound network traffic, <100 KB/s outbound)
My server is not too busy (~25% CPU, ~40% RAM, ~4 MB/s outbound network traffic, ~2 MB/s outbound)
When everything runs fine, I can transfer at 110 MB/s (they are on the same 1 Gbs switch, with Cat8 wires
My share is on a SSD (550 MB/s)
The network is not active
I have configured vlc so it should buffer (file & network caching) 10 seconds

# iperf result
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-60.00  sec  6.53 GBytes   935 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-60.00  sec  6.53 GBytes   934 Mbits/sec                  receiver

Is there some parameters I can set so it stop freezing? Or tests I can perform so I understand where the bottleneck is?
